# Is affiliate marketing halal?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia, business

I have a blog and I want to use affiliate marketing to make money from it. I can assure you that the products are absolutely halal. But I've not used most of them. But I know that they are very good.

So, is it haram to promote those products?

Comment: what kind of this product first to determine if it haram or halal

Comment: It is technology products like web hosting, software, hardware, etc. I can assure you that the products are absolutely halal. But the problem is I've never used them. So, can I promote the product I myself haven't used?

Comment: That is halal as my viewpoint. Many Muslims have a phobia in technology as it has a widespread fame of spreading nudity,music or others bad stuff. But as I read about ur business type it is halal actually. It is actually a platform and less connectivity with such spreading. But if their such possibility of that you have to be aware to manage ur business honestly

Comment: Thank you very much @ZunaidMahmud for this explanation. I think I have got a good answer.

Comment: Zazakallah Khairan